# jQuery Ajax load() with a callback fadeTo() only honors fadeTo() opacity first time

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein, fadeout, fadeto

Page in question is located at: http://pull4parkinsonsfoundation.org/clinical_trials

I am Ajax loading a `<ul>` of links into an ID'd area by clicking a nav link that filters what's seen by fading out the current html and fading in the new. That all works.

Based on input I found here on ***SO*** I learned that fading ***in*** the div in question after first fading it out needs to be handled in the callback of the `load()` call.

Still, all good so far. (Actually, for clarity, I'm using a `fadeTo('slow',0.2)` and `fadeTo('slow',1)` for the fadeout/fadein as an actual fadeOut/fadeIn makes page elements shift).

The problem is that when another nav link is clicked to choose a new filter for the list, the `fadeTo()` is always to zero, not the 0.2 that's coded. This is not a *horrible* problem, but I would prefer the effect of 20% visibility so that the area doesn't completely disappear.

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#trial_recruitment a.loader').live('click', function() {
        var load_url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#trial_recruitment a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#article_briefs #open_trials').fadeTo('slow', 0.2).load(load_url + ' #open_trials', function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
        });
            return false;
    })
});
```

Any ideas, or is this just one of those weird jQuery behaviors?

Comment: Check console log, you have 2 errors

Comment: no errors in Firebug console. perhaps that first fadeTo() (now removed) but can't see why that would cause an error.

Comment: Error 1 : Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of undefined site.js:105

Comment: Error 2 : GET http://localhost:3000/sidebarv2.js?apikey=qh59bx8dt9tiv6pn1nhesq  completed:72

Comment: the localhost error looks more like a browser extension on your end throwing an error more than anything remote, no? selectedIndex error is a piece of unrelated jQuery for action on another page. Not sure why it would be acting up but will look.